# Implementing Facebook Connect for iPhone using xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, facebook

I'm having trouble getting Facebook Connect working. I (attempt) to follow the instructions located at http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/ but it seems to be for earlier versions of xcode. Here are the steps I'm taking.

- Create a new View Based App
- Download the SDK from their [link](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/src.zip)
- Copy the FBxxxx.h files from the FBConnect folder inside of the src folder into my projects directory
- Create a new group named FBConnect under my project in xcode
- right click add new files and select the files that are already within my project
- go through the rest of the steps on the page creating an application and writing the example code

It seems that I've set everything up correct then I get the follow error when I build my project.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JetPackViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLoginButton", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JetPackViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JetPackViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with how I am importing the files into my project. So how do I fix this or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Facebook Connect SDK has been deprecated.  Pull down the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) from Github.  It comes with a working example and all you need to do is replace your appId in two places.  If you run into issues upgrading it to Xcode 4, see this [guide on upgrading](http://webbuilders.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/no-architectures-to-compile-for-facebook-ios-sdk-upgrade-to-xcode-4-0/).

Comment: for example, it tells you to drag and drop which is not possible with xcode 4

Answer (score 1):

In addition to copying the headers into your project, you also need to copy the implementation (.m) files. Make sure they're included in your target's Compile Sources build phase after you copy them in.