# How can I add the Facebook Connect SDK to my project in Xcode 4.1?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing Facebook Connect for iPhone using xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210268/implementing-facebook-connect-for-iphone-using-xcode-4)

How can I add the Facebook Connect SDK to my project in Xcode 4.1? I cannot drag the folder FBConenct to my project.

Answer (score 0):

To add the SDK on your pages should only be inserted:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```